# jdbc SQL query cancellation using java

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two Oracle Database instances, both 11g version.

I have written a simple java code to execute a query and then cancel it while it is running..
This is my code.

```
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@mydb1:1521:orcl","username","***");

Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    private Statement tstmt;
    public Runnable init(Statement tstmt) {
        this.tstmt = tstmt;
        return this;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            System.out.println("Running the thread....");
            Thread.sleep(1500);
            tstmt.cancel();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException...");
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("SQLException...");
        }
    }
}.init(stmt)).start();
```

I am basically invoking the statement.cancel while the query is running and I want to handle it in the exception.
The SQLException is triggered when I run this against db1. However it doesn't happen against db2.

I am not able to figure out why is this difference in behavior. Is there a setting for cancel query that can be enabled/diabled in the db??

Comment: Are you sure statement is still running? You can also use setQueryTimeout JDBC method. You should use JDBC drivers ver. at least 18c. Oracle uses OOB flag in TCP headers in "cancel" packet. Maybe your FW discards those packets. Try to set: `System.setProperty("oracle.net.disableOob", "true");`

Comment: @ibre5041  Is the cancellation getting logged somewhere? Where should I look to see 
 the cancel event  log?

Comment: On db server no. On network level you can use tcp dump to track a packet having OOB flag set. On client's side you should receive an exception with reason containing Oracle error: "ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation"